# SELinux blocks tomcat web application to load Java native library (JNI) - how to configure SELinux on Centos 7?

Tags: security, centos7, java, selinux, library

I have a Centos 7 with Tomcat installed and **tomcat** user

```
ls -l /var/lib/tomcat
total 0
drwxrwxrwx. 5 root tomcat 84 Jul  3 13:18 webapps
```

SELinux is enforcing and a Java web application which tries to load Java native library (JNI) from shared object files .so in /tmp/ folder cannot work.

```
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/app/gdal_java/2018.07.03.14.52.59/libosrjni.so: 
/tmp/app/gdal_java/2018.07.03.14.52.59/libosrjni.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Permission denied
```

If I disable SELinux, there is no problem to load these files in the Java web application. The permission of this file is:

```
ls -lZ /tmp/app/gdal_java/2018.07.03.14.52.59/libosrjni.so
-rwxrwxrwx. tomcat tomcat system_u:object_r:tomcat_tmp_t:s0 /tmp/app/gdal_java/2018.07.03.14.52.59/libosrjni.so
```

How can I configure SELinux to allow **tomcat** user to load these files from */tmp/app/* folder?

I have tried with this command and restart tomcat but it still has same error

```
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t tomcat_tmp_t '/tmp/app_*/(.*)?'
```

Comment: Look in `/var/log/audit.log` for the deny message and use `audit2allow` to generate an updated policy.

Answer (score 1):

I use audit2allow tool from @jordanm's comment  to allow tomcat can have multiple permission (read, execute) on this /tmp/app folder.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/sect-security-enhanced_linux-fixing_problems-allowing_access_audit2allow

```
cat /var/log/audit/audit.log  | audit2allow -a
```